# How do I create a simple script which executes (in Linux) a sequence of commands?

Tags: perl, scripting

Premise: I know (a bit of) Python.

I'm working on a a R Sweave (R + Latex) document.

To compile and execute it from command line I need to execute the following commands from console:

```
R CMD Sweaver fn.Rnw
pdflatex fn.tex
okular fn.pdf
```

Where

```
fn
```

varies from time to time (but is the same in all of the instructions).

Since I'm doing this many times, I'd like to make the process automatic and as simple as writing something like:

```
script <fn>
```

where **fn** is the parameters used in the 3 single commands.

I think this is somehow possible in Python or Perl, but I don't know where to begin.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perl is overkill for this.  Do it in a shell script.  Better yet, learn `make`, which is the right tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a script containing:

```
R CMD Sweaver "$1.Rnw"
pdflatex "$1.tex"
okular "$1.pdf"
```

If you name it `foo.sh`, you could invoke it by saying:

```
sh foo.sh fn
```

or

```
bash foo.sh fn
```

and the shell would use the positional parameter that was passed in order to perform the variable substitution.

Comment: Yes, shell script will be the way for this. here $1 will be the argument after <file-name>

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example Perl script (untested):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;

my $fn = shift or die "Usage: $0 function_name\n";

# I assume this needs to exist?
-e "$fn.Rnw" or die "$fn.Rnw does not exist.\n";

0 == system( 'R', 'CMD', 'Sweaver', "$fn.Rnw" ) or die "R failed.\n";
0 == system( 'pdflatex ', "$fn.tex" ) or die "pdflatex failed.\n";
0 == system( 'okular ', "$fn.pdf" ) or die "R failed.\n";

exit 0;
```

Write that to a file, make it executable with `chmod +x`, and you should be set.

Comment: I tried the script. Error " /usr/lib/R/bin/Rcmd: 62: exec: Sweaver: not found " . I assume 0 == system ('R'  , ...) it's different than "R CMD Sweaver fn.Rwn". Can you explain me the system (...) row, please?

Comment: For e.g. the first system() call, it simply executes the 'R' command and supplies all other values as parameters. It's interesting that you get that error - is "Sweaver" another script or command? Is it a file that you own?

Comment: Sweaver is a library of R statistical software. I assume it's no more than a string which is internally handled to run a program (written according to R syntax)

Comment: Try using the full path to the binary R